# google drive api dont know where it saves the file but when fetched it shows the saved but not the others

Tags: google-drive-api

I used the google drive api to insert a text file...

**Build Service**

```
function buildService() {

$DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';

if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost')
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'xxxxxxxx-privatekey.p12';
else
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/xxxxx-privatekey.p12';

  $key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
  $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
      $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      array($DRIVE_SCOPE),
      $key);
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setUseObjects(true);
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
  return new Google_DriveService($client);
}
```

**Retrieve Files**

```
function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
  $result = array();
  $pageToken = NULL;

  do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
      }
      $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

      $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
      $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      $pageToken = NULL;
    }
  } while ($pageToken);
  return $result;
}
```

**Creating an instance and inserting**

```
$service = buildService();

$file = new Google_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('My document');
$file->setDescription('A test document');
$file->setMimeType('text/plain');

$data = "contents";

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array('data' => $data,'mimeType' =>'text/plain',));

print_r($createdFile);

echo '<br>------<br>';
```

**Retrieving files**

```
$ret = retrieveAllFiles($service);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($ret);
```

1. As in the fist call i insert a file...
2. in the second call i am trying to list all files...
3. when i try to list i could see only the inserted file but not the others which i could see in my drive by logging into docs.google.com. i am already having 6 files online
4. as per the documentation i created service account with the private keys and the service account email.

**so where will that file be store and how do i list all other files in the root of google drive?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting files in the application-owned account represented by the service account.

If you want to manage (insert/list/...) files in another domain user's Drive account, you'll have to perform Domain-wide delegation: https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

Comment: no it is me and my account. i want to copy files from my website to google drive at the background without my interference. besides, is it possible to see all the files i have inserted using drive.google.com in a browser. i tried but i cannot see the files i have inserted. suggestions...?

Comment: The way you are authenticating is the one used for service accounts. If you only need to access your account, then the standard auth process will suffice. You can request offline access to insert files in background

Comment: oh... that is what i had been searching for... i haven't seen any topic related to offline access in drive api documentation... could you drop a reference here? meanwhile, i am checking on it... first time into google drive api taking a long time...

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth for more details about the OAuth flow